# My photo is too big to fit my HTMLcanvas what can I do?

Tags: css, reactjs, html5-canvas, maps, web-component

I created a map using HTMLcanvas and a photo, but the photo is too big, so it's alright when im trying to render it in normal size, the canvas width and height are the same as the photo's,
but when im zooming in it crashes, becasue the size of the canvas is too big.
I have 2 events for the zoom-in (2_fingers_touch and wheel);

I also tried to center the view by a selected dot, but the canvas aint moving :D
im clue less how to continue from here.
this is my code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { MapProps, TrackPoint, pwgParamsType, Pin } from '../../common/types/YotiMaps.types';
import { CrisisContext } from '../../contexts/CrisisContextProvider';
import { useGeolocation } from '../../common/hooks';
import Loading from '../Loading/Loading';
import crisisLocationImageSrc from '/maps/crisis-location-icon.png'
import pinImageSrc from '/maps/pin.png';
import locationImageSrc from '/maps/self-location-icon.png'
import mapImgSrc from '/maps/suger.png';
import { Crisis } from '../../common/types';
import { convertLatLonToITM } from '../../pages/unit-conversion-page/components/conversionHelperFunctions'
import { PopupContext } from '../../contexts/PopupContextProvider';
import './maps.scss';

const YotiMaps: React.FC<MapProps> = (props) => {
  const { height, width, maxPins } = props
  const { alertPopup } = useContext(PopupContext);

  const pgwData = useRef<pwgParamsType | null>(null)
  const pins = useRef<number>(0);
  const mapImage = useRef<HTMLImageElement | null>(null)
  const [pinArray] = useState<Pin[]>([])
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);

  const pgwFilePath = '/src/components/Map/suger.pgw';
  const { crisis } = useContext(CrisisContext);
  const myLocation = useRef(useGeolocation())

  // SCALE THINGS 
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1.5);
  let initialTouchDistance = 1;

  // Drawing the Images first time
  const pinImage = new Image();
  const locationImage = new Image();
  const crisisLocationImage = new Image();
  pinImage.src = pinImageSrc;
  locationImage.src = locationImageSrc;
  crisisLocationImage.src = crisisLocationImageSrc;

  // draws the map first time
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvas) {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx) {
        const map = new Image();
        map.src = mapImgSrc
        map.onload = () => {
          redrawCanvas(ctx, map);
          mapImage.current = map
        };
        getPgwData();
        canvas.addEventListener('click', handleCanvasClick);
        canvas.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheelChange, { passive: false });
        // Clean up event listener
        return () => {
          canvas.removeEventListener('click', handleCanvasClick);
          canvas.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheelChange)
        };
      }
    }
  }, []);


  // *****FUNCTIONS****** 

  const redrawCanvas = async (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, image: HTMLImageElement) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    drawMyLocation(ctx);
    drawMeetupLocation(ctx, crisis)
  };

  const drawMyLocation = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => {
    let x: number = 0;
    let y: number = 0;
    let fixedCoordinates = { easting: 0, northing: 0 }
    const context = ctx
    myLocation.current()
      .then((coords) => {
        x = coords.longitude;
        y = coords.latitude;
        context.drawImage(locationImage, x, y, locationImage.width * 2 / 3, locationImage.height * 2 / 3);
        fixedCoordinates = convertLatLonToITM(y, x)
        console.log(fixedCoordinates);
      })
      .catch((error: ErrorOptions) => {
        alertPopup(`מיקומך לא נמצא`, "red");
        console.error('Error loading self location', error)
      });
  }
  const drawMeetupLocation = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, crisis: Crisis | null) => {
    if (!crisis) return <Loading />
    const stringMeetup = crisis.meetup
    const meetup = { lat: parseFloat(stringMeetup.lat), lng: parseFloat(stringMeetup.lng) }
    // const meetup = { lat: 100, lng: 100 }
    ctx.drawImage(crisisLocationImage, meetup.lat, meetup.lng, crisisLocationImage.width, crisisLocationImage.height);
  }

  const getPgwData = async () => {
    try {
      const pgwResponse = await fetch(pgwFilePath);
      const pgwData = await pgwResponse.text();
      parsePGWFile(pgwData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading PGW file:', error);
    }
  }

  const calculateItmCoordinates = (clickX: number, clickY: number, pgwData: pwgParamsType | null,): { transformedX: number, transformedY: number } => {
    let tempObj: { transformedX: number, transformedY: number } = { transformedX: 0, transformedY: 0 }
    if (pgwData) {
      const transformedX = pgwData.pixelSizeX * clickX / scale + pgwData.originX;
      const transformedY = pgwData.pixelSizeY * clickY / scale + pgwData.originY;
      tempObj = { transformedX, transformedY }
    }
    return tempObj;
  }
  const calculatePixelCoordinates = (easting: number, northing: number, pgwData: pwgParamsType | null): { fakeX: number, fakeY: number } => {
    let tempObj: { fakeX: number, fakeY: number } = { fakeX: 0, fakeY: 0 }
    if (pgwData) {
      tempObj.fakeX = (easting - pgwData.originX) * scale / pgwData.pixelSizeX,
        tempObj.fakeY = (northing - pgwData.originY) * scale / pgwData.pixelSizeY
    }
    return tempObj;
  }

  const parsePGWFile = (pgwDataFromFetch: string): void => {
    const parameters = pgwDataFromFetch.trim().split('\n');
    const pixelSizeX = parseFloat(parameters[0]);
    const rotationX = parseFloat(parameters[1]);
    const rotationY = parseFloat(parameters[2]);
    const pixelSizeY = parseFloat(parameters[3]);
    const originX = parseFloat(parameters[4]);
    const originY = parseFloat(parameters[5]);
    pgwData.current = {
      pixelSizeX,
      rotationX,
      rotationY,
      pixelSizeY,
      originX,
      originY,
    }
  };


  // **********EVENTS-FUNCTIONS************

  const handleCanvasClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas?.getContext('2d');
    if (canvas && ctx) {
      const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      const clickedX = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const clickedY = event.clientY - rect.top;
      if (pinArray.length < maxPins) {
        let coordinatesObj: { transformedX: number, transformedY: number } = calculateItmCoordinates(clickedX, clickedY, pgwData?.current)
        ctx.drawImage(pinImage, clickedX - 23, clickedY - 40, pinImage.width, pinImage.height);
        const newPin: Pin = { id: pins.current, x: clickedX, y: clickedY, actualY: coordinatesObj.transformedY, actualX: coordinatesObj.transformedX };
        pins.current++;
        pinArray.push(newPin)
        console.log(pinArray);
      } else {
        let coordinatesObj = calculateItmCoordinates(clickedX, clickedY, pgwData?.current)
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (mapImage.current) {
          redrawCanvas(ctx, mapImage.current);
          for (let i = 1; i < pinArray.length; i++) {
            ctx.drawImage(pinImage, pinArray[i].x - 23, pinArray[i].y - 40, pinImage.width, pinImage.height);
          }
          ctx.drawImage(pinImage, clickedX - 23, clickedY - 40, pinImage.width, pinImage.height);
          const newPin: Pin = { id: pins.current, x: clickedX, y: clickedY, actualY: coordinatesObj.transformedY, actualX: coordinatesObj.transformedX };
          pinArray.splice(0, 1);
          pinArray.push(newPin);
          pins.current++;
          console.log(pinArray);
        }
      };
    }
  };
  function getTouchDistance(touch1: React.Touch, touch2: React.Touch): number {
    const dx = touch2.clientX - touch1.clientX;
    const dy = touch2.clientY - touch1.clientY;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  }

  const handleCanvasTouchStart = (event: React.TouchEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
    if (event.touches.length >= 2) {
      const touch1 = event.touches[0];
      const touch2 = event.touches[1];
      initialTouchDistance = getTouchDistance(touch1, touch2);
    }
  };

  const handleCanvasTouchMove = (event: React.TouchEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
    if (event.touches.length >= 2) {
      const touch1 = event.touches[0];
      const touch2 = event.touches[1];
      const currentTouchDistance = getTouchDistance(touch1, touch2);
      const zoomLevel = currentTouchDistance / initialTouchDistance;
      setScale(zoomLevel);
    }
  };

  const handleWheelChange = (event: WheelEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, event.deltaY));
    const scaleIncrement = 0.001;
    setScale(prev=>  prev*delta+scaleIncrement)
  }

  return (
    <canvas
      id='yotiMaps'
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={14000 * scale}
      height={4116 * scale}
      style={{ transform: `scale(${scale})` }}
      onTouchStart={handleCanvasTouchStart}
      onTouchMove={handleCanvasTouchMove}
      onWheel={handleWheelChange}
    />
  );
};

export default YotiMaps;
```

i tried to cut the photo to 7 equal pieces but it looks bad when u zoom-in in only one photo and u can see the other photo didnt zoom-in,

i thought maybe try to make 2 equal canvas but i wanted to see if anyone has a better idea before i do that.

at the canvas render, i tried to make the size as the scale size but it crushes so it's a mistake.

Comment: Don't change the canvas resolution (`canvas.width` and/or `canvas.height`) when zooming in. Change the canvas display size (`canvas.style.width` and/or `canvas.style.height`) OR better yet don't make the canvas larger than the display device and scale the photo when drawing on the canvas.  eg `ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width * pixelSizeX, image.height * pixelSizeY)`